# Sum of Multiple Vectors

Tags: r

So the behavior of the following code:

```
x =  c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
print(sum(x - 3))
```

is
[image]

But what is the behavior of using multiple vectors in a `sum`?

For example:

```
print(sum(x - y - 3))
print(sum(x - y - z - 3))
```

Comment: Element-wise operations, then sum, i.e. vectorized.

Comment: With recycling if lengths are different : `c(1,2,3,4)-c(1,2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Let's think like this way:

For

```
sum(v1 - v2 - 3)
```

it is equivalent to

```
v <- v1 - v2
sum(v - 3)
```

where `v` is a vector from the element-wise difference between `v1` and `v2`, and `sum(v-3)` is the same as what you did to `sum(vector - 3)` in your post.

---

## Remark

If you have unequal lengths between multiple vectors, the recycling rule will be applied (see comment by @Waldi)

Comment: perhaps a comment on recycling if lengths are different would also be useful

Comment: @Waldi Yes, exactly.

Comment: What is recycling?

Comment: @NoName You can read this https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-art-of/9781593273842/ch02s03.html